# Clear log file while the logging process is running

Tags: linux, shell, logging

Assume before clear the log file, file size is **1.5M xxx.log**.
I'm using **sudo cp /dev/null  xxx.log** command to clear the log file.
After running the script, file size change to '0'.
But If i make some action, log size increase to **1.5 xxx.log** with a lot of **white space**.

When I googling it need to stop writing process first!
But I don't want to stop the writing process, is there is any other ways.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88808/empty-the-contents-of-a-file

Comment: Change the process creating the file so it checks the file size before writing and starts a new one if it is too big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

```bash
truncate -s 0 xxx.log
```

Answer (score -1):

When the log size increases, the *logical size* increases. It creates a sparse file. You could check using `ls -ls xxx.log` or `du xxx.log` to check. The file on disk does not use 1.5MB.

(edited because of negatives feedback)

What I tried to explain, is when you `cp /dev/null xxx.log`, you truncated the file. But the application, will continue to write on it, but *at its current position*. So you create a sparse file, it is empty from the start of the file to the last write of the application.

The `ls -lh` will print what I called the `logical size`, but `du -hs` will only print the number of block **really allocated**.

Comment: Yes Disk usage -> du xxx.log not use 1.5. Is there any other way, my requirement need to effect in ls -lh also. Thank you.

Comment: ls -lh will only print the `logical` view. What is important for you, the space *used* by your file log, or the space your file log *seems* to use?